# Tags with formatting in them render incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, design

All formatting should be stripped out of the `[tax:tag-name]` feature.

Right now, you get some funny results.

[tag:`Oops`]  `[tag:`Oops`]`

[tag:*Test*] `[tag:*Test*]`

[tag:****] `[tag:****]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in dev.  Any tag link with non-tag characters as the "tag name" will be ignored.

This should go out sometime tonight.